# 'URL no longer Exist' issue when trying to open a link from inline visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, iframe, inline, clickjacking

I have an **inline VF page** like following in my application that have multiple links that is created using html anchor tags.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="acc__c" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0">
<div>
  <a href = "/check" >check</a>
  <a href = "/check1" >check1</a>
</div>
</apex:page>
```

When i click any of the links, the page is getting redirected in the same section of the parent page but the issue arrives when i **right click** and click on **open in a new tab** button over the link, then in new tab it shows 'URL no longer Exist'. and get a link like following

https://na85.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=0661U000000bqPr&ic=1&linkToken=VmpFPZxNakFWT1MwdS15MHhORlF4TURvMU5qb3pOUzQyTkRaYSx3UlNYRVpWWk1qdFJITHd1NGg5ZXlDLFlXSmtNR0po

Comment: This post would be improved if you **[edit]** it to contain the relevant markup.

Comment: edited the question